# ArgumentException calling Expression.IfThenElse

Tags: vb.net, linq, expression-trees

I'm trying to build this LINQ query:

```
Result = Result.Where(Function(Row) If(IsDBNull(Row(7)), False, Convert.ToInt32(Row(7)) > 10))
```

`Result` is a `IEnumerable(Of Object())`.

I manage to build the expression with this code, but at the last line, I get an error message.

The code I have is this:

```
Dim whereMethod = GetType(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static).First(Function(m) m.Name = "Where").MakeGenericMethod(GetType(Object()))
Dim convertMethod As MethodInfo = Nothing
Dim rowParameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Object()), "Row")
Dim isdbnullMethod As MethodInfo = GetType(System.Convert).GetMethod("IsDBNull", New Type() {GetType(Object)})
Dim expr As Expression = Nothing
Dim tempexpr As Expressions.LambdaExpression = Nothing
convertMethod = GetType(System.Convert).GetMethod("ToInt32", New Type() {GetType(Object)})

tempexpr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.IfThenElse(
                             Expression.Call(isdbnullMethod,
                                 Expression.ArrayAccess(rowParameter, Expression.Constant(7))),
                             Expression.Constant(False),
                             Expression.GreaterThan(
                                 Expression.Call(
                                     convertMethod,
                                     Expression.ArrayAccess(rowParameter, Expression.Constant(7))),
                                 Expression.Constant(10))),
                         rowParameter)
```

Then I call:

```
expr = Expression.Call(whereMethod, Result.AsQueryable.Expression, Expression.Lambda(tempexpr.Body, rowParameter))
```

And at this line I get this error:

[image]

What can be the problem? Without the `IfThenElse` it works. Also this:

```
Result = Result.Where(Function(Row) Convert.ToInt32(Row(7)) > 10)
```

**EDIT**

Is this because the `If` operator is an "Action" method and doesn't returns a value?

Btw. the `Expression.IfThenElse` uses the `IIf` function. How could I use the `If` function?

**EDIT II**

I think, I found it: `Expression.Condition`. It uses `IIf` too, but with this, I don't get an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Edit II is correct: [`Expression.IfThenElse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.ifthenelse(v=vs.110).aspx) returns void, making the whole expression an `Action`. [`Expression.Condition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340500(v=vs.110).aspx) returns whatever the type is in the `ifTrue` parameter, making your expression `Expression(Of Func(Of Boolean))`, which is what you want.

As an aside, I don't believe it's really calling the `IIf` function. That's simply a debug view of what is going on. I don't think it's really calling either of those VB.NET-only methods